# Open xlsm file in linux?

Tags: linux, spreadsheet

For all my spreadsheet needs, I've found Open/Libre Office works fine, and I can receive xls and xlsx files from colleagues, and send files to them.  However, I have recently been sent a large xlsm file, which is of course full of MS Excel macros, and so won't open in LibreOffice calc, which uses a different macro engine.

Is there a linux application for such files?  MS Excel under Wine? CrossOver? Something else?

Comment: The most 100% sure way if you have Windows and Office licenses would be to install Office and Windows in a virtual machine. Although, if it runs under Wine, that's more, well, close to $HOME. LibreOffice has a macro conversion engine, make sure that it is enabled. It won't catch everything, but may help.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run the macros that are included/referenced in the `.xlsm` file on Linux then there is no software that I've come across or was able to find through searching that can do this. The major problem is that the underlying macro languages are completely different between MS Excel of LibreOffice.

Without an application your next best options are to either use something like CrossOver followed by Wine.

There is also a 3rd option, which I've never used, that's web based called [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/). Zamzar allows you to upload files and convert them to a variety of formats. The formats are [listed here](http://www.zamzar.com/conversionTypes.php), but I did not see .xlsm listed. However many people listed this as an option on various forums so it might still be worth a look.

Comment: I had many VBA scripts for my thesis work. But then later changed the VBA scripts to shell scripts. Now, I will try to run the excel macros using the options that you have mentioned.